# Как создавать кнопки через цикл и присваивать к ним функцию в PyQt5?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, lambda, сигналы-слоты

У меня есть код, который создаёт кнопки. Но после нажатие, выдаёт значение `False`, а не имя кнопки.

```
        self.x= 20
        self.y= 20
        self.r= 0

        self.button_packed(["Математика","Биология","Физика"] )
        
    def button_packed(self,name_list):
        for bts in name_list:
            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
            button.setText(bts)
            button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.x,self.y,100,20))
            button.clicked.connect(lambda bts=bts: print(bts))
            self.y = self.y + 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.x = 20
        self.y = 20
        self.r = 0

        self.button_packed(["Математика", "Биология", "Физика"] )
        
    def button_packed(self, name_list):
        for bts in name_list:
            button = QPushButton(self)                             # ??? self.tab_2 
            button.setText(bts)
            button.setGeometry(QRect(self.x, self.y, 100, 20))
# --------------------------------------> vvv <-------------------------------------
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, bts=bts: print(bts))
            self.y = self.y + 50 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(700, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]